# Python - reshaping an array

Tags: python, reshape, numpy-ndarray

I'm new to Python and working on reshaping multi-dimensional arrays. I have two 2D arrays whose shapes are (21,2048) and (107,2048) and I take the outer product to get a new array of shape (43008,219136). But I want my new array to have a shape of (21,107,2048) how do I do that?

eg:

`a = np.ones(shape=(21,2048)) b = np.ones(shape=(107,2048)) c = np.outer(a,b)             # shape: (43008,219136)`

Doing `c.reshape((21,107,2048))` gives a ValueError `cannot reshape 9424601088 into (21,107,2048)` which makes sense because the size of `c` is `9424601088` whereas, the size of the desired array (whose shape = (21,107,2048)) is 4601856. Should I be using reshape() at all then?

Gist of what I'm doing/need to do:

```
a = R.std(axis=1)  # shape of R = (21,107,2048)
b = R.std(axis=0)
c = np.outer(a/a.mean(),b)

# next part needs me to divide 'c' with another array before I can use it.
X_median = np.median(X,axis=1)[:,np.newaxis,:]    # shape of X = (21,107,2048)

# normalise
nXe = c / X_median  # shape of X_median = (21,1,2048)
```

Apologies if it's trivial, still learning! thanks!

Comment: If that's the desired shape of your output array l don't think that `np.outer` is what you're looking for. From the documentation (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html), "Input is flattened if not already 1-dimensional." I.e. a is being turned into a 43008 element array and b is being turned into a 219136 element array.

I'd guess that you want something like $c_{ijk} = a_{ik} * b_{jk}$, but not knowing your actual problem that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

you should remember that, the number of data should be equal after shape.

In your case 21*107*2048 = 4601856 != 9424601088, this leads the error.

Comment: Yes! I think I need to add a new axis to both a and b before taking the outer product? Okay, nope don't think that helps.

Comment: I think you need c.reshape((-1, 21, 107, 2048))

Comment: Wouldn't that give (2048,21,107,2048)?

Comment: yes, -1 mean auto calculate the dimension

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an output array of the form $c_{ijk} = a_{ik} * b_{jk}$, `np.outer` is not what you're looking for in this case.

From [The documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html).

> Input is flattened if not already 1-dimensional.

I.e. your input 2-d arrays are being turned into 1-d arrays.
Instead, you should be reshaping the first input array *before* multiplying them together.

```
print((a.reshape(21,1,2048) * b).shape)
# (21, 107, 2048)
```

It's worth reading up on [numpy array broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to understand how arrays interact with each other. (For what it's worth, `np.outer` is equivalent to `a.reshape(-1, 1) * b.reshape(-1)`)

Comment: Thank you, Elliot! I guess I need to just compute each element of c separately using a loop maybe?

Comment: l mean, if there's a solution with a loop that's a good start, but in general you want to vectorize numpy operations as much as possible. (Python loops are _sloooow_).